# One of them is not like the others: why is std::vector::size implemented in terms of pointers on all major standard library implementations?

Tags: c++, std, libstdc++, libc++

Playing randomly on godbolt (as one does) I found that `std::vector::size()` is implemented as a difference of pointers while I was expecting it to just return a class data member. `std::vector::capacity()` is similar. What is weird is that all other standard containers (except `std::deque`) store the size as a data member. Even `std::string` on libstdc++ and Microsoft's STL stores its size as a data members (on libc++ it looks like size info storage is optimized with SSO info, still the size is explicitly stored and not computed as difference of pointers).

[Here is the godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/_JruWR) with all the containers' size on libc++, libstdc++ and microsoft's STL. Some excerpts below:

```
f_vec4:  //std::vector<std::int32_t>
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        sub     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        sar     rax, 2
        ret
f_vec8:  // std::vector<int64_t>
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        sub     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        sar     rax, 3
        ret

f_list:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        ret

f_map:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+40]
        ret
```

Why is `std::vector::size` the only container size implemented as pointer difference while all other containers store their size? Is is something in the standard? Is it an optimization?

Comment: The elements of a `std::vector` are guaranteed to be contiguous.   So, given a pointer to the first element and a pointer to one-past-the-end, a simple pointer subtraction can be used to obtain the number of elements i.e. the `size()` or the `capacity()` if the implementers decide to do that.   Most other containers are not guaranteed to be contiguous, so don't have the option to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is std::vector::size implemented in terms of pointers on all major standard library implementations?

Because it can be implemented in terms of pointer subtraction. And because the standard library implementers chose to do that.

> Is is something in the standard?

No. I'm sure that it would be standard conforming to store the size as a member.

> What is weird is that all other standard containers (except std::deque) store the size as a data member.

This is hardly surprising. No other data structure can use pointers as iterators besides an array.

`std::string` is implemented as an array, so it could also use pointer subtraction. If it isn't done so, it is because the implementers chose to not do so. This may, or might not be due to convenience related to small string optimisation.

Comment: Using pointers instead of a size gets in the way of implementing SSO for `std::string`, which implementers generally consider worthwhile.

Comment: @Deduplicator How does it get in the way?

Comment: Well, SSO means double-duty for all bytes but the flag-bit. But if the members all are pointers for the long representation, where can one take that one flag-bit from? One can probably design even around that, but it makes things more cumbersome imho.

Comment: @Deduplicator I was thinking that they could abuse implementation specific details of pointer representation... But now that I think about it, it might not be a great option. So I agree with your statement.

Comment: In libc++, it stores the size when in "small string" mode, but not in "large string" mode.

Answer (score 2):

Helf the answer here:

All other containers need to store the size because they don't keep their elements in a contiguous region of memory (`list`, `(unordered)_(multi)map`, `(unordered)_(multi)set`). `std::string` does store the elements in an array, but because of the SSO (small string optimization) that array can be dynamically allocated or contained within the structure so the best strategy is to store its size.

`std::vector` is the only container which has the option to store pointers to begin and end (and capacity end). Why all the standard libraries implement `std::vector` with begin-end and not with begin-size I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::some_algorithm(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ...);
```

Now imagine `vector` is storing the size of the vector. Then let's assume it's implemented like:

```
// in #include <vector>
namespace std {
template<typename T>
class vector {
    T *_Begin; // pointer to beginning of allocated space
    size_t _Size; // size of allocated space
    T* begin() { return _Begin; }
    T* end() { return _Begin + _Size; }
 };
...
}
```

Then `std::some_algorithm` could be inlined to:

```
std::some_algorithm(vec._Begin, vec._Begin + vec._Size, ...);
```

If our priority is object size, we would choose to store either end pointer or the count of objects in the vector. When we store the count of objects, we have to calculate the `end()` pointer by addition and we can return `size()` immiedately. When we would store the end pointer, then `end()` would be just a simple return, while `size()` has to be calculated from pointer difference and division by object size.

Most probably library implementators choose to optimize calculation for `end()` rather then for `size()`. Because the C++ algorithms are based on taking two pointer - beginning and end iterator, it's reasonable (for me) to assume that end pointer will be used a lot more often then size.

Comment: your assumptions about for-range is wrong. `vec.end()` is evaluated just once by standard requirement

Comment: Och it is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for . But the reason stands, only the example is wrong. The each loop part makes no sense. But still the reason is that `end()` is calculated more often then `size()`, so it's better to optimize `end()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict requiremnets on `size()` implementation execept for the complexity - it has to be constant. So one may speculate that `std::vector` just laverages the fact that its elements storage is contiguous because of a implementor's choice and/or potential benchmarks (even though such tiny change's effect is hard to imagine). Straight from standard:
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements.general#4

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Expression | Return type | Operational | Assertion/note | Complexity |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| a.size()   | size_­type   | distance(   |                |            |
|            |             |   ​a.begin(),|                |  constant  |
|            |             |   a.end())  |                |            |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

If I recall corrctly it was not always like that, for some time gcc's `std::list::size()` had linear complexity (in pre C++11 times).

Comment: how is storing size saving bytes? begin + end + capacity vs  begin + size + capacity_size seems like the same size to me.